# Adding 2D arrays to specific indexes in an empty 4D array

Tags: python, linux, numpy, multidimensional-array

I currently have ~40 years worth of daily ozone measurement datasets (which were 3D arrays with dimensions time (24), latitude (361), and longitude (576) respectively). Each day has its own data file.

I then created a 2D array (361, 576) for each day, averaging all of the data from each hour.

My next goal is to create one plot for each day of the calendar year (January 1st, January 2nd, etc.) that ranges through all of the years in my dataset. I'm trying to show the trend of ozone on each day through each respective year. For example, my first plot would be the trend of the daily average on January 1st from the first year to the last year in my dataset.

```
dims = np.shape(TO3) #Dimensions of original data (24, 361, 576)

avgTO3 = np.arange(dims[1]*dims[2], dtype=float).reshape(dims[1], dims[2]) #Creates new 2D array for daily averages 
avgTO3[:,:] = 0.0

for i in range(TO3.shape[0]):
  np.add(TO3[i], avgTO3, out=avgTO3)

avgozone = avgTO3 / 24.0 #Final 2D array of daily average

dailyavgdims = np.shape(avgozone)
  
dailyavgyear = np.arange(dailyavgdims[0]*dailavgdims[1], dtype=float).reshape(dailyavgyear[0], dailyavgyear[1])
dailyavgyear[:,:] = 0.0

dailyavgbyyear = dailyavgyear[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
dailyavgbyyear[:,:,:,:] = 0.0 #Empty 4D array with dimensions (361, 576, 365, 40)
```

Within the 4D array, the third dimension represents the calendar day (so it would likely go to 365), and the 4th dimension represents the year (which would be around 40).

My question is how I can add each of the 2D arrays to specific dimensions in the 4D array. Like how can I add the daily average of January 1st, 1980 (the first possible day) to the 4D array with dimensions (361, 576, 0, 0), and then January 2nd, 1980's 2D array to (361, 576, 1, 0) and so on? I'm finding it to be difficult, especially since I can't necessarily store these arrays anywhere else because of Linux. Any help is appreciated!

Sidenote: I know my code isn't too condensed, but that's something I'm not terribly worried about at the moment. I'm still trying to learn the in's and out's of Python and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
years = 40
days = 365
# random data for the example. You'd load an array, or hardcode in the dimensions
TO3 = np.random.randn(24, 361, 576)
# get average over first dimension
avgozone = TO3.mean(0)
# Create the empty array
dailyavgbyyear = np.zeros((*avgozone.shape, days, years))

for y in range(years):
    for d in range(days):
        # Load 3d array
        TO3 = np.random.randn(24, 361, 576)  # random data for the example
        avgozone = TO3.mean(0)  # get mean over first dimension
        dailyavgbyyear[:, :, d, y] = avgozone
```